# How do I get queryset containing all referenced objects with a specific user field?

Tags: python, django

I have two models similar to this:

```
class ContactDetails(Model):
  name = models.CharField()
  dept = models.CharField()

class Server(Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User)
  ip = models.GenericIPAddressField()                           
  hostname = models.CharField()
  contact = models.ForeignKey(ContactDetails)
```

I would like to get a queryset of all the ContactDetail objects that are referenced by a Server object that has a specific user. Is this possible in Django? I know what I have below won't work, but perhaps it gives an idea of what I'm trying to do:

```
ContactDetails.objects.filter(Server.user=request.user)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [lookups-that-span-relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

```
ContactDetails.objects.filter(server__user=request.user)
```